# Burning audio-disc from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, automation, cd-burning

Is there a command line utility for Windows from which you can make audio CDs out of MP3 r any other common audio format? If there's no true command line it should be able to be made with a input-list for the files so it can be used by a external program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use [CDRTOOLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdrtoolswin/). I had to recently burn a CD from MP3 files and this worked perfectly.

Comment: OOps; that version wasnt linked on the main cdrtools-page :( so it slipped under my radar; thxxes